# Chrome not saving Cookies across different subdomains

Tags: c++, google-chrome, http, cookies, jwt

I've written a very primitive C++ HTTP server and I want to support the JWT token using JWT-CPP. Basically, I have 2 endpoints:

- If the request is /auth/username, I will generate a JWT token with the username given in the URL.
- If the request is /verify, I will check the Cookie in the request header and look for a JWT token. If it exists, I will verify it and return the username in the JWT payload.

Here is the part of the code I send the response:

```
// Check and give JWT token
if (has_auth == 0 || auth_right == 0) {
      // HTTPGET[1] contains the URL requested. For example, 'auth/username'
      size_t pos1 = HTTPGET[1].find('/');
      size_t pos2 = HTTPGET[1].find('/', pos1 + 1);
      std::string mode = HTTPGET[1].substr(0, pos2);
      printf("JWT: mode is: %s\n", mode.c_str());
      if (strcmp(mode.c_str(), "/auth") == 0) {
         printf("JWT: Auth\n");
         size_t pos3 = HTTPGET[1].find('/', pos2 + 1);
         std::string username = HTTPGET[1].substr(pos2 + 1, pos3);
         printf("JWT: username is: %s\n", username.c_str());
         auto token = jwt::create()
                      .set_issuer("auth0")
                      .set_type("JWS")
                      .set_payload_claim("sub", jwt::claim(username))
                      .set_issued_at(std::chrono::system_clock::now())
                      .set_expires_at(std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds{86400})
                      .sign(jwt::algorithm::hs256{"secret"});
         auto verifier = jwt::verify()
                       .allow_algorithm(jwt::algorithm::hs256{ "secret" })
                       .with_issuer("auth0");
         auto decode = jwt::decode(token);
         std::string GiveJWT = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: myhttpserver\r\n" + CORS_header + "Content-type: text/plain\r\nSet-Cookie: token=" + token +
          "\r\n\r\n JWT token generated successful!\nYour token's username is: " + username + "\n";
         write(fd, GiveJWT.c_str(), GiveJWT.size());
         return;
      }
      //return;
   } else {
         std::string NeedAuth = "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\r\nServer: myhttpserver\r\n" + CORS_header + "Content-type: text/plain\r\n\r\nAuthorization failed\n";
         write(fd, NeedAuth.c_str(), NeedAuth.size());
   }

// Verify user's token
// rel_path contains the url or subdomain of the request. For example, the url here should be './verify'.
  if (strcmp(rel_path.c_str(), "./verify") == 0) {
      printf("Get in the verify\n");
      if (auth_right == 1) {

         auto decode = jwt::decode(success_token);
         std::string username = decode.get_payload_claim("sub").as_string();

         printf("username is: %s\n", decode.get_payload_claim("sub").as_string());
         
         std::string JWTConfirm = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: myhttpserver\r\n" + CORS_header + "Content-type: text/plain\r\n\r\nYour user name is: ?" + username + "\n";
         write(fd, JWTConfirm.c_str(), JWTConfirm.size());
         return;
      } else {
         std::string JWTConfirm = "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\r\nServer: myhttpserver\r\n" + CORS_header + "Content-type: text/plain\r\n\r\nWhate are you looking at?";
         write(fd, JWTConfirm.c_str(), JWTConfirm.size());
         return;
      }
   }
```

This is the HTTP header & response I got from accessing /auth/oreo:
[image]

I can see the server is supporting CORS in its header, so the cookie should be able to transferred across domains. However, If I switch to the endpoint /verify, that token cookie will not be carried. I know Cookies are suppose to be session-based, but is there anyway I can carry this cookie as long as the browser session exist?

Comment: Is the `/verify` endpoint using the same domain as the `/auth` endpoint? So, in your example, is it `http://mc17.cs.purdue.edu`? You mention subdomains in the title of the question, but then only give the example of a different path. If indeed you're using another domain then you have to set the cookie's domain to be the parent. Cookies can't be used across domains, and by default the cookie is saved with the domain of the serving site.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski Thank you for pointing that out. I was missing this part and I am able to make it work now. Although I did make a mistake in the question: I intended to say multiple paths, not multiple subdomains, which creates some confusion, but In the end, I am able to resolve this by adding a `Path=/` attribute to my cookie and the cookies can be shared across different paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the misinterpretation ahead. What I meant was a different path, not different subdomains. In the end, I resolved this by adding the "Path=/" attribute after my Cookie, which allows the cookies to be carried forward across different paths.

However, If you have stored the old cookie before, make sure you clear them first. This could be my endpoint's issue, but if I don't clear the cookies, the request will mysteriously hang even after I close the socket on the server-side. I'm not sure why though.